# Determine whether form input has focus

Tags: angularjs, validation, focus, onchange

I'm doing validation in AngularJS, and I have a div that is displayed if there are 3 types of errors.

For required I want to show the error message only if the page is submitted with empty value

```
<div class="error" data-ng-show="submitted && mainForm.email.$error.required" />
```

For the regex validation I want it to flag real-time, default behavior.

```
<div class="error" data-ng-show="mainForm.email.$error.pattern" />
```

The problem I'm facing is with minlength. I don't want to show it while they are typing. It's annoying because they haven't finished typing. I don't want to display it on submit either, I think that's too late. I'd like to show it when they are no longer in focus of the element.

If //mainForm.email.$focus existed I could simply do this

```
<div class="error" data-ng-show="mainForm.email.$error.minlength && 
!mainForm.email.$focus"/>
```

Anyone know of any way to do this kind of check or any non drawn out alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes it does 
you can use ngFocus and ngBlur for this purpose

here is the code

```
<form name="mainForm">
    <span ng-show="mainForm.email.$error.pattern && !focus">error here</span>
    <input name="email" ng-pattern="..." ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false" type="text" />
</form>
```

ngFocus and ngBlur take expression and ngShow shows upon true evaluation

Answer (score 5):

You need to read about ModelOptions, debounce and updateOn can delay model change trigger event or trigger change on DOM event https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Check the example on the page

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="userName"
           ng-model="user.name"
           ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
           ng-keyup="cancel($event)" /><br />

    Other data:
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.data" /><br />
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name"></span></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good to know. The only problem is that I still need real-time validation on Regex validation. I'm thinking of using ng-blur and setting a scope variable. I just dont want to have to do that for every field :(

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option is:

```
 <input type="text"
        name="searchText"
        ng-model="searchText"
        ng-blur="searchIsInActive()"
        ng-click="searchIsActive()"                  
        placeholder="Search">
```