# Angular JS retrieving in the controller the element who called the method

Tags: angularjs, methods, controller, element

i'm managing the focus on my view elements.

So the controller has an array named $scope.focus.

Within the view, in order to display the first element in the focus stack, i do:

In the view:

```
<div id="productFormContainer' class="container-fluid blabla" ng-if="hasFocus('productFormContainer')" tabindex="-1">
some div content
</div>
```

then in the controller :

```
$scope.hasFocus=function(elementId){
return $scope.focus[$scope.focus.length-1] == elementId;
}
```

But i'd like to refactorize, like :

in the view, simply asking "ng-if = 'hasFocus()'", without specifying the elements Id as an argument.
Then in the controller retriving the element's id that sended the method call through ng-if directive.

I forgot to mention that ng-if="hasFocus(this.id)" doesn't work because 'this' become something else than the element once processed inside the ng-if directive.

Until now, i failed constantly at trying to retrieve the elements who called the hasFocus method within the controller.

This focus management allows me to go back in the view by just pressing escape to go back to the previous shown view's element. It' maintain a clear display with only the required element shown to the user, and eases navigation with keyboard without having to any flags to manage it.

Any idea ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109047/angularjs-tell-if-form-element-has-focus

Comment: Does this mean that once the focus is lost from a div you can't ever go back to it? I would need to see the whole picture to understand what are you trying to achieve. How do you populate the focus array?

Comment: yes i made it to be able to go back to it. in the controller i do setFocus(elementId) so it put this element on top of the focus stack or roll back to it if it is allready present in the focus stack. then hasFocus returns true for this element and it's shown to the user. I didn't show the whole view's code, there is a keypress binding to each div that can be focusable, in order to make the keypress event (with escape', making the focus going back to the previous element. I dont have the code right here, i 'll post it on monday if you want.

Comment: @Anton Looks to me that you need a directive to do this, you shouldn't be doing this kind of stuff in your view $controller. If I see the code I should be able to sketch something for  you using directives.

Comment: yes, i tried to make a 'focusable' directive, but as it had to manage ng-if in it's inside, i didn't succeed in making the ng-if beeing handled by the digest process. In the console, ng-if was there in the compiled element, but it didn't work. having a 'focusable' directive who would handle on it's onw a id attribute (generate it if not existing), the keypress biinding and the ng-if call would be a greate thing. i'll post my whole code on monday. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: here's a bit of view code: